# Trim method not working for Array when reading from String

Tags: javascript, csv, trim

I have researched plenty of .trim method questions to see if someone had my same issue but I haven't come across it and I think it's because of something I did wrong and I just can't see it.

I want to extract the .CSV line and trim it, so I went ahead and did this:

```
const convertCSVLine = (csvline) => {
  const cell = csvline.trim().split(',');
  const id = cell[0];
  //get rid of spaces..
  const customer = cell[1];
  const product = cell[2].trim();
  const price = cell[3].trim();

  return new SalesOrder(id, customer, product, price);
};

const test = '101,Charlie Anderson, Bike, 10.00';

console.log('SALES ORDER:', convertCSVLine(test));
```

But for some reason I get this error in my browser when I trim those two lines:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'trim')

Like `.trim()` works on the first cell line (because its going to be reading a whole .CSV string altogether so I need to separate the lines) but then I want to trim the product and price part of the new array by themselves but now its throwing this error.

I'm relatively new to coding and have had a semester of Java so I know the pain, I'm just an intermediate programmer.

Comment: what's the value and type of the cell item that's causing the error?

Comment: @user1599011 Hi! Thanks for your response!!  The type should just be a string and the value for both cell[2] and cell[3] should be "bike" and "10.00". When I remove the trim method it works just fine, just outputs it with the spaces still there

Comment: Maybe they *should* be strings, but *are* they strings in reality?

Comment: @user1599011 D'OH PICKLES you're right my G, its coming out as undefined. I'm not sure why that is when it shouldn't know how many items will be in the array in the first place ! But cell[0] with a trim method works just fine but all the rest don't exist.. aw man, so sorry for the trouble

Comment: What does the variable `cell` contain after it's created?

Comment: @user1599011 Oh! Cell is supposed to contain and array of strings that are separated using the split method! Here's its output:
cell = (4) ['101', 'Charlie Anderson', ' Bike', ' 10.00']

Comment: It's working fine for me. (slightly modified since `SalesOrder` is not defined here) https://jsfiddle.net/13dqrj4t/1/#run

Comment: If cell[2] or cell[3] are undefined, it's because the split isn't finding enough commas in the string passed in.  You could check cell.length to make sure it's 4 or larger before trying to do those assignments.  Maybe some of the data is weird.

Comment: @user1599011 Both of you, thank you sosososo much for your help (and sorry for the late reply!) You even compiled it and I appreciate that very much I'm so glad to know I aint crazy lol cause I've made a function similar to this before and it worked just fine! And that makes so much sense! Once the split is done I'll see how many commas and spaces there are left by running it through a debugger! THANK YOU BOTH MAN! YOURE THE BEST